# Cannot change ownership/permissions of disk

Tags: permissions, mount, ext4, usb-drive, ownership

I have an EXT4 disk mounted on `/mnt/external` I have also tried mounting it on `~/EXTERNALMNT`. The disk is not an NFS share. It is an external USB drive. I can read from the disk but cannot write, unless I am root. This is in tune with the permissions: `rwxr-xr-x` and ownership `root:root`.

However, I need to be able to write to it without being root. Running `sudo chmod -R 777` on the mountpoint completes after a few seconds but does not actually change the permissions. `sudo chown -R murrax2:murrax2` results in the message `Operation not permitted` for every file/folder. Running `sudo chattr -a` and `-i` results in `Operation not supported while reading flags`.

I have tried accessing it via a Windows laptop via a program that allows EXT4 access, and I can write data and it persists (including when plugged back into my Arch PC). Why can't I change permissions/ownership, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Operation not supported while reading flags. -> `e2fsck`?

Comment: How did you mount the disk? Have you inadvertently wrongly specified uid/gid for the mount?

Comment: Try /etc/fstab: use the usual entries for mounting a disk then installed of using just "defautls", use  "auto defaults,uid=?,gid=? " were the ?'s are your numerical uid and gid. And you can add umask too. Typically they use a UUID of the disk instead of /dev/sdb1 for instance. Look in your /etc/fstab file for example.

Comment: Make sure the UIDs GIDs match.

Answer (score -1):

I could not mount with gid/uid specified. It would give the generic `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock`. In the end, wiping the drive, creating a new partition table and new filesystem fixed it.

Comment: You could have run `e2fsck` instead.